# How to customize the "Read more" link in D7?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, navigation

By default, the "Read More" link wrapped in the tag `<li>`. How i can change this tag to `<p>`?

I tried to use hook `theme_node_view_alter(&$build)`, but i couldn't find in `$build` required variables.

Answer (score 0):

[`node_build_content`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_build_content/7.x) is where it's originally set. You should be able to override this by implementing `hook_node_view` or `hook_entity_view`. The links should be in `$node->content['links']`